# Fanfiction where Snape finds blind Harry Potter and adopts him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read a fanfiction a while ago where the Dursleys abandon Blind Harry and Snape finds him, and eventually finds he is a potter (the Potters are alive by the way, and had left him at the Dursleys) and Snape adopts him. Also Voldemort knows about it and was fine with the adoption.

Harry is also friends with Draco and calls Narcissa his aunt.

Please help me find it.

Comment: At first, I thought this said that "the Dursleys abandon *and* blind Harry...," and all I could think of was *Equus*:  https://playbill.com/article/equus-with-harry-potter-star-radcliffe-begins-london-previews-feb-16-com-138577

Comment: Does the first chapter have a reveal that his uncle has been raping Harry on nights when Aunt Petunia has refused him?

Comment: I think so actually